# Bash parameter expansion escaped value without quotes

Tags: bash, docker

I need to share data between the host and Docker container, using `-v` parameter:

```
$ docker -v host_dir:container_dir image_name
```

In this specific case, I need to share the present working directory. Normally it could be done like this

```
$ docker -v `pwd`:container_dir image_name
```

But that fails if the present working directory contains any spaces (or other characters that should be escaped). There's a special way to expand a parameter value to be safely reused for input:

```
$ docker -v ${PWD@Q}:container_dir image_name
```

But that doesn't help, too, as the path is enclosed in single quotes, and that results in an illegal parameter value: `-v '/present/working/dir with spaces':container_dir`. The correct syntax would be `-v /present/working/dir\ with\ spaces:container_dir`.

So, my question is, how to expand parameter value, escaping the special characters with backslashes rather than enclosing the value in quotes?

Comment: `docker -v "$(pwd)":container_dir ...` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have the variable inside quotes on your shell command line:

```
$ docker -v "`pwd`:container_dir" image_name
or
$ docker -v "$PWD:container_dir" image_name
```

Or else bash will perform word splitting after the command substitution or parameter substitution occurs.

What happens here is not escaping with backslashes: this just makes bash recognize you don't want word splitting to occur there, which makes it be passed as a single argument to your program (in this case, docker).

Comment: The latter shouldn't have @Q, since this would add a layer of escaping

Comment: That is correct, thanks! I forgot to remove it after pasting the line.